# ASP.NET MVC Image button/action link that goes to a javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I can't seem to generate a image button or action link that will go to a javascript function.

Examples:

```
<input type="image" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clear1.png") %>"  onclick="NCRClear();" />
```

The above example will try to do a form submit.  I just want it to go to the Javascript function NCRClear().

```
<a href=<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clear1.png") %>" alt="Clear" /> onclick="NCRClear();">Clear</a>
```

I can't get the action link syntax correct with a image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `href` makes no sense.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an 'image' input type that I believe performs a form submit by default, could you just use a link that wraps your image, something like -

```
<a href="#" onclick="NCRClear();"><img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clear1.png") %>"/></a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Do you know how to remove the border around the image?

Comment: @Elim99, use style="Border:none" in image tag to remove border around image.